# How to input from the Python debugger (pdb)

Tags: python, pdb

The question is best illustrated by the following simple example. I am using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) to debug the following script (it is Python 3):

```python
astring = input("input here: ")
```

when stepping in the above line, I get the following prompt and type "abc":

```
input here: abc
```

But whatever I input from the keyboard, I get an error, e.g.,

```
NameError: "name 'abc' is not defined"
> /home/wang/tmp/test.py(4)<module>()
-> astring = input("input here: ")
```

How can I input when debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect function for your purposes in Python 2.  Use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) rather than [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Actually I was using Python 3. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the "abc" entered is considered an evaluation. However, your program is input("input here "), but the example you give is "input here:" and the output from pdb says "input a line:".

I don't know whether they are they same program due to these differences. Try entering n (for next line of code) instead of abc and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for help. I used old error after updated the script. The question has been corrected now. When entering n, it returns same error with "abc" replaced by "n".

Comment: @WangXiaojie No ... you're either **not** using python 3 (else something has overwritten your `input` function).  On python 3: `python3 -c "x = input('input here:')"` works while `python2.7 -c "x = input('input here:')"` leads to a `NameError: ...`.  Perhaps you should do `input sys; print(sys.version)` and see what you're running?

Comment: @donkopotamus: You are right! Thank you so much! I was using "pdb test.py" to try out pdb, where "test.py" has a  "#!/usr/bin/python3". I took as granted it was using python3!